# Can't get unread email from K-9 email app

Tags: android, email, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to get a list of unread email from K-9 email client.  I'm using the following code:

```
public class EmailReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
public static final Uri k9uri = Uri.parse("content://com.fsck.k9.messageprovider/inbox_messages/");
static String[] messages_projection = new String[] {"subject", "preview", "unread"};


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    try {
        Context mContext = context;
        Cursor curSt = mContext.getContentResolver().query(k9uri, messages_projection, "unread='true'", null, null);
        curSt.moveToFirst();
...
```

The problem is that its returning all messages that are in the inbox whether they are read or not.  I've looked at the contents of the "unread" column from both a read and unread message and they do have the values 'true' and 'false' respectively.  I've looked for a solution for this but can't come up with one.  Has anyone ever run into this problem.  And if so is there a fix for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just filter the array and you are done.

Comment: Thanks  That's just what I needed.  I used a hash map to gather the subject and body of the unread emails.  Here is the code I used:

Comment: `Cursor curSt = mContext.getContentResolver().query(k9uri, messages_projection, null, null, null);
   curSt.moveToFirst();
   while (!curSt.isAfterLast()) {
    if (curSt.getString(curSt.getColumnIndex("unread")).equals("true")) {
     emails.put(curSt.getString(curSt.getColumnIndex("subject")), 
       curSt.getString(curSt.getColumnIndex("preview")));
    }
    curSt.moveToNext();
   }`